# Logarithmic vs sequential density of a sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory, harmonic-analysis, limits-and-convergence

Given a sequence of complex numbers $\{a_n\}_n$, one says that this sequence admits $a$ as a *sequential density* if 
$$\underset{N_s\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{1}{N_s}\sum_{n=1}^{N_s} a_n = a$$
where $N_s = 2^{2^s}$ for instance. The sequence admits $a$ as a *logarithmic density* if 
$$\underset{N\to\infty}{\lim}\frac{1}{\log N}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} a_n = a.$$
If the the sequence has a sequential density, does it also have a logarithmic one, with the same limit ?

**Motivation:** In a paper called [Problems of Almost Everywhere convergence related to harmonic analysis and number theory](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02807252), Jean Bourgain states that for any function $f$ in $L^2(\mathbf{T})$ the sequence of its Riemann sums $\{R_nf(x)\}$ admits $\int_0^1f$ as a logarithmic density. In the proof, it turns out that Bourgain reduces this convergence to an $L^2$-maximal inequality

$$\left\Vert\underset{N_s=2^{2^s}}{\sup}\frac{1}{N}\left\vert\sum_{n=1}^NR_nf\right\vert\right\Vert_2\leq C \left\Vert f \right\Vert_2 $$

which actually proves the sequential density of the sequence $\{R_nf(x)\}$ for almost every $x$ in $\mathbf{T}$.

In number theory, the [Davenport-Erdös](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davenport%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem) theorem states the equivalence of this two notions of densities for sets. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639136/natural-density-and-logarithmic-density) for instance. I don't know where to find a proof of this theorem in order to adapt it for sequences.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Also posted on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318273/logarithmic-vs-sequential-density-of-a-sequence)

Comment: So it is considered impolite to simultaneously post on both sites. If you're not sure, try MSE first, and if there is no answer in 2 or 3 days, consider posting on MO. The issue is that this leads to wasted effort.

Comment: So I think the answer to your question is "no" unless you have some kind of growth conditions on the $a_n$. For instance if $a_{2^{2^n}}=2^{2^n}$ and $a_{2^{2^n}+1}=-2^{2^n}$ and all other terms are 0, the first sequence has limit 1, whereas the second sequence has limit 0.

Comment: As usually I will link to the discussion of [meta-tag:cross-posting] on [MathOverflow Meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se/2638#2638). (And a [similar post on Meta Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088). This is meant as a kind of follow up on Anthony Quas' comment.)

Comment: Sorry for publishing on the two forums. I understand and won't do that again, I'm not familiar with all of this. I was about to delate my post from MathStackExange when @Martin Sleziak answered me. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "no" even if we assume that the $a_n$ are bounded. For example, take $a_n=1$ if the fractional part of $\log_2\log_2 n$ is between $0$ and $\frac12$ (equivalently, if $n$ is between $2^{2^k}$ and $2^{2^{k+1/2}}$ for some integer $k$), and $a_n=0$ otherwise. Then the sequential limit will equal $0$, but the lim sup of the logarithmic-density expression equals $1$ while its lim inf equals $0$.